# Prediction about tags on which you are most and least likely to answer

Tags: support, tags, data-analysis

Some time ago there was a blog post about someone analysing what tags SO users answered on and coming up with the five most and least likely tags that this user would answer on in the future. The post included a link (template) where you could view the results for at least yourself, possibly for any user.

For the fun of it, I would like to keep tabs on that prediction as I am moving into other fields of software development. For the life of me I can't remember the link for my own prediction page and two hours worth of googling has not yet led me back to that original blog post.

Could someone please help me and provide the link to that blog post and/or the appropriate URL for my own prediction page?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That would be https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current. (Yes, that URL takes you to your own report, and anyone else's to theirs.)

I know [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) wrote about this, not sure if anyone else worked on it and if so, anyone else wrote about it. Kevin's post can be found [here](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow).

Note that it's still experimental for now. I for one could definitely see room for improvement: while [php](/questions/tagged/php) is indeed one of my top tags, I've been extremely inactive there in the past couple of years. I haven't even answered a single [php](/questions/tagged/php) question this year, and I disagree with the tool saying I'm more likely to answer questions with that tag, mainly because I haven't worked with PHP in so long and got bored with the tag.

Comment: Why didn't I know about this `:-o`. This is nice :)

Comment: Kevin does address this specifically in his blog post: *"Surprisingly, despite the seemingly breakneck speed of change in software, looking at recent history when calculating the site average is a much worse predictor than considering all-time.  Likewise when looking at user history, even for very highly active users, recent activity is a worse predictor than all time."* You might just be the weirdo here. :-)

Comment: @Cody Gray: Sheesh.

Comment: That tag future report is *awesome* though. Somehow I missed the link when I first read the blog post. It is almost creepy how accurate it is for me. The preferred tags are exactly the ones I would choose for myself.

Comment: Would you say that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week&search=boltclock) is more accurate? The tags listed for you are `css, css-selectors, html`.

Comment: @Dave Chen: Not sure, given that it's simply tags where I've earned the most upvotes in a certain period of time. That said I have more answers in those three tags than [php], and so I'm more likely to collect upvotes/earn rep in those tags.

Comment: Is still [Kevin Montrose](http://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose) working on it?

Comment: @Llopis: Why are you asking me? I'm not him.

Comment: I can't ask him directly and I wanted to call more attention to this topic. Note that I didn't tag you in my comment but as you mention him in your post it made sense to post this here instead of under the question.

Comment: @Llopis: Yeah but the only person who's going to get notified of this is me, not him.