# How do I include a link in my profile that refers to the current site?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

For example, if I want to link to the [tag predictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194505/prediction-about-tags-on-which-you-are-most-and-least-likely-to-answer) page:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current

I could include something like this in the "About Me" section of my profile:

```
http://CURRENT_SITE/users/tag-future/current
```

click "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts", and it would expand to

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/tag-future/current

in my Bitcoin.SE profile,

https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current

in my StackOverflow profile, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that `/current` will be the visitor's, right? (You will see yours; but anyone else will see theirs instead.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relative links do what you're asking. Place this

```
[Tag predictions](/users/tag-future/current)
```

in your profile, and your Bitcoin.SE profile should link to

```
http://www.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/tag-future/current
```

while your StackOverflow profile should link to

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current
```

This should work for any SE page, not just the tag predictions page. It doesn't work for the website field of your profile, however; relative links only appear to be expanded in the About Me section.

Comment: As an aside, `/current` refers to the visitor/viewer, not to the user who links to it. Not very useful in a user profile, I'd say.

Comment: @Arjan True; note that `/current` is part of the tag prediction link, however; simply including `/users/tag-future` in your profile won't work.