# Suggestions of problems for users basing on their knowledge/skills/solved problems

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-watching

Is there a way to suggest the user some problems to solve based on their knowledge/ skills/ suggested answers? 
Sorry if that topic was already disscussed, I didn't find anythig similiar. :)

If not, I think it could use keyword analysis to suggest topics/ problems after the user is logged on.

What do you think?

OK, i see that you're pionting to INTERESTING TAG solution but thats not my point. I see that the idea is not yet clear- it's often with something new.

Imagine suggestion automation that works like on Amazon. Lets say you searched for Stephen Hawking Book "A Brief History of Time". In result you get the book AND below other books by the author and RELATED books. This is kind of prediction tool I'm talking about. For start it could show full topics list but in time it would be filtered to ones that matches user activity.

I'm new user for the site. It is very not practical form me to waste a time for filter topics when some script can do it for me. This is IT science, isn't it?

I hope I explained my idea, if not don't hesitate to correct me ;).

Comment: You can favourite tags that will point out the questions with topics you are interested in. Also, how would the website know your level/area of knowledge and skills besides those you say you have?

Comment: @Amber It could analyse visited and/ or answered threads. Then it could suggest the problems automaticaly.

Comment: related: [Prediction about tags on which you are most and least likely to answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194505/prediction-about-tags-on-which-you-are-most-and-least-likely-to-answer)

Comment: In regards to your update: There is also the 'related' column to the right of questions that shows questions similar to the question you are currently looking at. This would be a feature similar to the example of amazon recommendations you gave. What you are essentially asking for is merging the 'interesting' and the 'related' lists(But correct me if I'm wrong), which would be a nice feature, but with the current two lists existing, unnecessary.

Comment: @Amber, you're moving in right direction :). It should be something like you've described but visible from your account profile. When you're logged on you can't see that. What you described (right side of this page for example) is useful but I'm not sure if an algorithm behind it is based on my description.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking that the Stack Exchange application should suggest a list of questions to users based on their knowledge, skills, and solved problems then the [Interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) does just that.

However, if you are suggesting that a user should be able to send a question to specific users/experts then no this is not possible and an [earlier request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71727/ask-a-question-and-notify-users-on-specific-users-list) has already been declined.

Comment: @ Aziz Shaikh Something in between... Current solution require user action to suggest some topics. I think about automated solution.

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski usually automated systems need an initial input. For the interesting tab, that input comes from your favorite/ignored tags, past answers, etc. You may want to add specific usage / feature scenario in your question, so that community can better understand your feature-request.

Comment: @ Aziz Shaikh, could the system basing on user visited threads and sucessfully answered threads suggests new topics automatically? First advantage is that topics will go to the most interested/ skilled people in the field. Second advantage is that it could shorten the time of answer. It could work similiar when you search for something in the Amazon, for example music. It can suggest similiar topics for you to solve.

Comment: I believe the interesting tab already does that. If you think otherwise then please update your question (using the edit link) and add details about how the interesting tab should be improved.

Comment: yes but it's not automatic.

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski But it is...It's not like there's a person sitting there thinking about which questions to mark as "interesting".  It's an automated process.

Comment: @Servy, it is not automatic in a sense that you have to pick the tags. I think about compleate automatic process.

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski If it doesn't have any information then it can't really pick interesting results.  It needs some information.  That's one of the ways in which it gets that information.  It can't just read your mind.  I'd be much more concerned if it could.

Comment: @Servy, it is so hard to not at the beginning not sort any suggestions, and in time (through experience gained by the system filters) suggests the filtered results?

Comment: @AndrzejJasienski That's exactly what it *does* do...

Comment: Obviously you're missing the point. Where is automation? It doesn't working from the begining- it starts later after user tags selection. Read Amber reply above- She catched the idea. Try to be more open minded. Frm my point o view even moving those LINKED/ RELATED elements to user profile page would be helpful.